# Added callback in collection#observerChanges has Template.instance() = null

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I set listener on mongodb collection with event observerChanges

I want it to push the new entry to `ReactiveVar` in order to be used in template dynamically.

If i insert the data by submitting to the form, it works fine... `Template.instance()` is an instance of `Blaza.Template`.

However, if i insert record in mongodb manually, `Template.instance()` become null

Could you please help explain why can't i access Template among this different event?

Thank you so much.

```
cursor.observeChanges({
    added: function(id, doc) {
        if (usersLoaded) {
            task = Template.instance().curTasks.get();
            task.push({id: id, text:id});
            Template.instance().curTasks.set(task);
        }
    }
});

Template.body.onCreated(function bodyOnCreated() {
    this.curTasks = new ReactiveVar([]);
});

Template.body.helpers({
    tasks: function() {
        return Template.instance().curTasks.get();
    }
});

Template.body.events({
    'submit .new-task'(event) {
        // Prevent default browser form submit
        event.preventDefault();

        // Get value from form element
        const target = event.target;
        const text = target.text.value;

        // Insert a task into the collection
        Tasks.insert({
            text,
            createdAt: new Date(), // current time
        });

        // Clear form
        target.text.value = '';
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is just no template context at all when the observer fires based on a db change - your observer is defined outside of a template. Try moving your observer into your `.onCreated` code so that `Template.instance` is defined

```
Template.body.onCreated(function bodyOnCreated() {
    this.curTasks = new ReactiveVar([]);
    cursor.observeChanges({
      added: function(id, doc) {
        if (usersLoaded) {
          task = Template.instance().curTasks.get();
          task.push({id: id, text:id});
          Template.instance().curTasks.set(task);
        }
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: I also tried that but it still not working. same error.

Comment: Do you actually have an html template defined or are you just using body?

Comment: Yes, i have `body.html`. Insert input box is stay there, and that input box work. so strange.

Comment: But do you have `<template name="body">` or just `<body>`?

Comment: Just `<body>` and i try wrap it with `<template name="body">` but the console said `imports/ui/body.html:1: Template can't be named "body"`

Comment: ok, so you have no actual template to refer to. `<body>` is not a Blaze template. Just do `<template name='content'>` for example and attach your events and handlers to that.

Comment: I tried but no luck.. it still not working...
does it have any other work around? i want to listen when new data insert to mongo collection and put it into html...